# How to Modify Custom Attribute X of all users/groups in an OU?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, custom-attributes

I need to change Custom Attribute 1 and 2 for ~500 mailboxes in Exchange.
The user accounts linked with mailboxes are spread over 10-15 OU's within AD and each different OU needed different custom attributes.

Ideally, I dont want to run the following command twice for each mailbox

```
Set-Mailbox user@domain.com -CustomAttribute1 "X"
```

SUDO

Get a list of all users, email groups, contacts, rooms in a given OU in AD
Change each Custom attribute 1 to X
Change each Custom attribute 2 to X

Comment: For any given OU, do you need to set the custom attributes for every mailbox in the OU, or is there some selection criteria in effect other than just the OU of the mailbox?

Comment: The criteria for the custom attribute will be a shortened version of the name of the OU that each user/group is in. 
e.g. all users in the OU LUCAS will have LUC as their attribute1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an LDAP filter:

```
(|
  (objectCategory=person)
  (&
    (objectCategory=group)
    (!
      (groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2147483648)
    )
  )
  (msExchResourceMetaData=ResourceType:Room)
)
```

The above matches the following object types:

- users and contacts: `(objectCategory=person)`
- distribution groups: `(&(objectCategory=group)(!(groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2147483648)))` (technically this means: groups that are not security groups)
- room resources: `(msExchResourceMetaData=ResourceType:Room)`

You can select the AD objects matching that filter with [`Get-ADObject`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617198.aspx) and modify their properties with [`Set-ADObject`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617254.aspx):

```psh
$ou   = 'OU=some unit,DC=example,DC=com'
$fltr = '(|(objectCategory=person)' +
          '(&(objectCategory=group)' +
            '(!(groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2147483648)))' +
          '(msExchResourceMetaData=ResourceType:Room))'

Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter $fltr -SearchBase $ou -SearchScope Subtree |
  Set-ADObject -Replace @{
    'extensionAttribute1' = 'X'
    'extensionAttribute2' = 'X'
  }
```

I'm not entirely sure about the attribute names, since I don't have an Exchange at hand. You must use their LDAP names here, not any fancy alias.

Comment: With this, how would I assign the custom attribute 1 value to each object that it returns?

Comment: Is there a filter that can be run in Exchange Management Console?